# Discord JS Type error with .addStringOption Commandbuilder

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm so confused with this, I'm trying to add an option within an option but I keep getting a type error but I can't see any problems.. I'm fairly new to JS

```
async function main() {
  const classCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("class")
    .setDescription("Class setups")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("assault_rifle")
        .setDescription("Assualt Rifles")
        .setRequired(true)
        .addStringOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("gun")
            .setDescription("Select an assault rifle.")
            .setRequired(true)
            
        )
    );

  const commands = [classCommand.toJSON()];

  try {
    console.log("Started refreshing application (/) commands.");
    await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID), {
      body: commands,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting

```
TypeError: option.setName(...).setDescription(...).setRequired(...).addStringOption is not a function
```

Tried to find the typo!

Answer (score -1):

```
async function main() {
  const classCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("class")
    .setDescription("Class setups")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("assault_rifle")
        .setDescription("Assault Rifles")
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("gun")
        .setDescription("Select an assault rifle.")
        .setRequired(true)
    );

  const commands = [classCommand.toJSON()];

  try {
    console.log("Started refreshing application (/) commands.");
    await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID), {
      body: commands,
    });
    console.log("Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error refreshing commands:", err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a description of your solution, be specific on what was changed and why. Do not only dump the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).